# update table fieds based on trigger inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

In a project, user will key in data in a software and data will be export into SQL Server 2008 R2

Once SQL Server identify there is an inserted data (new row), it will trigger code to update table base on business rule.

Comment: any one can help on this. thanks

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: @DaleM: Apparently there had been a question there initially, before the post was edited. (I would've said, "vandalised", if it was someone other than the OP who edited it.)